# Make Ubuntu host ignore NIC, and let VM guest fully control it

Tags: networking, virtualbox

Is it possible to make a Ubuntu desktop host (running on a physical machine) ignore a network interface card (NIC, ethernet), and let a virtual box guest take full control of that NIC regarding IPs, etc?

The Ubuntu host has access to the network through another NIC.

If this is possible, could it be done in a simple way (using the graphical Network Manager). Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: ...and how would that card function, being ignored by the host OS?

Comment: It would ignore the network configuration, not the recognition that the card is installed. My question is, can Ubuntu delegate network configuration of a NIC to a VM guest OS, ignoring all the traffic that passes through it?

Answer (score 5):

Edit your /etc/network/interfaces file (hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run `sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces`) to add the following lines:

```
auto <nic-name>
iface <nic-name> inet manual
```

it will make the interface go up with no IP address and NetworkManager will not manage it.

Then in the VM network configuration select **Bridged Adapter** and point it to the NIC you want to use:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Eric, I will try your solution and give some feedback soon.

Comment: On ubuntu with Netplan, what is the recommended approach? I use netplan to rename the device currently.

Answer (score 1):

I remember I did that long time ago, interface had to be **"up"** to be usable by the guest so I gave **0.0.0.0** address to the host interface.

Comment: clearly @eric-carvalho solution is better,